# How can I implement a popup dependent on a query string?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add a popup with javascript which is triggered by a query string of the URL. I want the popup to stay hidden unless the query string is attached to the URL. I'll be using the popup mostly for redirects and any messaging that I want to display relating to the redirect.

I've tried using a combination of different functions I've used previously and can't get it to work, so I was just wondeirng if someone could take a look through and tell me where I'm going wrong.

The redirect with query string will be something like this:
https://www.example.com/?fromoldsite

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    var fromOldURL = window.location.href;

    if (fromOldURL.indexOf('fromoldsite') !== -1) {
        function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
        if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('redirectPopUp').style.display = "none";
        else  document.getElementById('redirectPopUp').removeAttribute('style');
        window.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                PopUp('show');
                }, 3000);
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #redirectPopUp {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        z-index: 1001; }

    #popUpContent{
        padding: 100px;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        background-size: cover
        position: relative;
        margin: 200px auto; }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="redirectPopUp">
    <div id="popUpContent">
        <h2>Popup Content Here</h2>
        <h6>Popup Message Here</h6>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the popup to show up only if the url contains "fromoldsite" and to pop up after 3 seconds. At the moment, the popup is showing up automatically regardless of the URL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your popup is displaying simply because you didn't call `PopUp("hide");` yet.

Furthermore the function definition of **PopUp** is inside the if block that evaluates the query string. Move it above, outside of the if block.

Lastly the **setTimout** function should just be triggered if the query string is present.

Your corrected code should look like this:

```
<script>
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
  if (hideOrshow == 'hide')
    document.getElementById('redirectPopUp').style.display = "none";
  else
    document.getElementById('redirectPopUp').removeAttribute('style');
}

var fromOldURL = window.location.href;

if (fromOldURL.indexOf('fromoldsite') !== -1) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    PopUp('show');
  }, 3000);
}

PopUp("hide");
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried ammending the code with your recommendations but I'm still having the same problem in the popup showing up on page load regardless of the URL. 

I tried  making the PopUp function's 'else' statement add a 'block' display instead of removeAttribute, then made the else statement to the second if/else trigger the PopUp('hide') function, but it still didn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: No, actually that should have fixed your probem. Looks like the problem is elswhere - can you post your full code that clearly shows the faulty behabiour?